# 'select sum' does not work in one table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

```
*-- Struttura della tabella `confmiele`
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `confmiele` (
  `idconf` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dataconfmiele` date NOT NULL,
  `codconfmiele` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `nomeconfmiele` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `boxconfmiele` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `pesoconfmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,
  `numconfmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,
  `totconfmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,
  `noteconfmiele` varchar(300) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=15 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
--
-- Dump dei dati per la tabella `confmiele`
--
INSERT INTO `confmiele` (`idconf`, `dataconfmiele`, `codconfmiele`, `nomeconfmiele`, `boxconfmiele`, `pesoconfmiele`, `numconfmiele`, `totconfmiele`, `noteconfmiele`) VALUES
(2, '2015-09-02', 'GPO15SET', 'GIPPOMIELE', 'VASO VETRO 1000', 1000, 1, 1000, ''),
(4, '2015-09-02', 'GPO15SET', 'GIPPOMIELE', 'VASO VETRO 1000', 1000, 1, 1000, ''),
(5, '2015-09-02', 'GP15SET', 'GIPPOMIELE', 'VASO VETRO 1000', 1000, 10, 10000, ''),
(6, '2015-09-03', 'GP15SET', 'GIPPOMIELE', 'VASO VETRO 1000', 1000, 1, 1000, ''),
(7, '2015-10-07', 'GP15SET', 'GIPPOMIELE', 'VASO VETRO 1000', 1000, 10, 10000, ''),
(8, '2015-10-07', 'GP15SET', 'GIPPOMIELE', 'VASO VETRO 1000', 1000, 10, 10000, ''),
(9, '2015-10-08', 'GP15SET', 'GIPPOMIELE', 'VASO VETRO 1000', 1000, 1, 1000, ''),
(10, '2015-10-08', 'GP15SET', 'GIPPOMIELE', 'VASO VETRO 1000', 1000, 1, 1000, ''),
(11, '2015-10-08', 'GP15SET', 'GIPPOMIELE', 'VASO VETRO 1000', 1000, 1, 1000, ''),
(12, '2015-10-08', 'GP15SET', 'GIPPOMIELE', 'VASO VETRO 1000', 1000, 1, 1000, ''),
(13, '2015-10-08', 'GP15SET', 'GIPPOMIELE', 'VASO VETRO 1000', 1000, 1, 1000, ''),
(14, '2015-10-08', 'GP15SET', 'GIPPOMIELE', 'VASO VETRO 1000', 1000, 1, 1000, '');
--
-- Indici per le tabelle scaricate
--
--
-- Indici per le tabelle `confmiele`
--
ALTER TABLE `confmiele`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`idconf`);
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT per le tabelle scaricate
--
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT per la tabella `confmiele`
--
ALTER TABLE `confmiele`
  MODIFY `idconf` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=15;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;*
```

`select sum` works in this table:

```
*SELECT SUM(numconfmiele) FROM confmiele WHERE codconfmiele = 'GP15SET' AND boxconfmiele = 'VASO VETRO 1000'*
```

However, on the second table:

```
--
-- Struttura della tabella `dettconffattmiele`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dettconffattmiele` (
  `iddettconffatt` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dataconffattmiele` date NOT NULL,
  `idfatt` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `codconffattmiele` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `nomeconffattmiele` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `boxfattmiele` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `numconffattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,
  `totpesoconffattmiele` int(7) NOT NULL,
  `uniteurofattmiele` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,
  `eurofattmiele` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=24 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dump dei dati per la tabella `dettconffattmiele`
--

INSERT INTO `dettconffattmiele` (`iddettconffatt`, `dataconffattmiele`, `idfatt`, `codconffattmiele`, `nomeconffattmiele`, `boxfattmiele`, `numconffattmiele`, `totpesoconffattmiele`, `uniteurofattmiele`, `eurofattmiele`) VALUES
(1, '2015-09-02', 10, ' GP15SET', ' GIPPOMIELE', 'VASO VETRO 1000', 5, 5000, '10.00', '50.00'),
(2, '2015-09-02', 11, ' GP15SET', ' GIPPOMIELE', ' VASO VETRO 1000', 5, 5000, '10.00', '50.00'),
(3, '2015-09-02', 12, ' GP15SET', ' GIPPOMIELE', ' VASO VETRO 1000', 5, 5000, '10.00', '50.00'),
(6, '2015-09-03', 19, ' GP15SET', ' GIPPOMIELE', ' VASO VETRO 1000', 1, 1000, '1.00', '1.00'),
(7, '2015-09-03', 20, ' GP15SET', ' GIPPOMIELE', ' VASO VETRO 1000', 1, 1000, '1.00', '1.00'),
(8, '2015-09-03', 21, ' GP15SET', ' GIPPOMIELE', ' VASO VETRO 1000', 1, 1000, '1.00', '1.00'),
(9, '2015-09-03', 22, ' GP15SET', ' GIPPOMIELE', ' VASO VETRO 1000', 1, 1000, '1.00', '1.00'),
(10, '2015-09-03', 23, ' GP15SET', ' GIPPOMIELE', ' VASO VETRO 1000', 1, 1000, '1.00', '1.00'),
(11, '2015-09-03', 24, ' GP15SET', ' GIPPOMIELE', ' VASO VETRO 1000', 1, 1000, '1.00', '1.00'),
(12, '2015-09-03', 25, ' GP15SET', ' GIPPOMIELE', ' VASO VETRO 1000', 1, 1000, '1.00', '1.00'),
(13, '2015-09-03', 26, ' GP15SET', ' GIPPOMIELE', ' VASO VETRO 1000', 1, 1000, '1.00', '1.00'),
(14, '2015-09-03', 27, ' GP15SET', ' GIPPOMIELE', ' VASO VETRO 1000', 1, 1000, '1.00', '1.00'),
(15, '2015-09-03', 28, ' GP15SET', ' GIPPOMIELE', ' VASO VETRO 1000', 1, 1000, '1.00', '1.00'),
(16, '2015-09-03', 29, ' GP15SET', ' GIPPOMIELE', ' VASO VETRO 1000', 1, 1000, '1.00', '1.00'),
(17, '2015-09-03', 30, ' GP15SET', ' GIPPOMIELE', ' VASO VETRO 1000', 1, 1000, '1.00', '1.00'),
(18, '2015-09-03', 31, ' GP15SET', ' GIPPOMIELE', ' VASO VETRO 1000', 1, 1000, '1.00', '1.00'),
(19, '2015-09-03', 32, ' GP15SET', ' GIPPOMIELE', ' VASO VETRO 1000', 1, 1000, '1.00', '1.00'),
(20, '2015-09-03', 33, ' GP15SET', ' GIPPOMIELE', ' VASO VETRO 1000', 1, 1000, '1.00', '1.00'),
(21, '2015-09-03', 34, ' GP15SET', ' GIPPOMIELE', ' VASO VETRO 1000', 1, 1000, '1.00', '1.00'),
(22, '2015-09-03', 35, ' GP15SET', ' GIPPOMIELE', ' VASO VETRO 1000', 1, 1000, '1.00', '1.00'),
(23, '2015-09-03', 36, ' GP15SET', ' GIPPOMIELE', ' VASO VETRO 1000', 1, 1000, '1.00', '1.00');

--
-- Indici per le tabelle scaricate
--

--
-- Indici per le tabelle `dettconffattmiele`
--
ALTER TABLE `dettconffattmiele`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`iddettconffatt`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT per le tabelle scaricate
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT per la tabella `dettconffattmiele`
--
ALTER TABLE `dettconffattmiele`
  MODIFY `iddettconffatt` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=24;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

the same `select sum` does not work:

```
SELECT SUM(numconffattmiele) FROM dettconffattmiele WHERE codconffattmiele = 'GP15SET' AND  boxfattmiele =  'VASO VETRO 1000'
```

I don't really understand. Why?
The codes are the same and I work on one server.

Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Tipo di server: MySQL
Versione del server: 5.5.31-log - Source distribution
Versione protocollo: 10
Utente: root@localhost
Codifica caratteri del server: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

Apache/2.2.12 (Linux/SUSE)
Versione del client del database: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.8-dev - 20102224 - $Id: 65fe78e70ce53d27a6cd578597722950e490b0d0 $
Estensione PHP: mysqli Documentazione
Versione PHP: 5.3.17
phpMyAdmin

Informazioni sulla versione: 4.4.4

Comment: Did your query works if you exclude *WHERE* clause?

Answer (score 0):

You have `, ' GP15SET',` with space in data.

But in your query `WHERE codconffattmiele = 'GP15SET' ...`

but **' GP15SET'** not equal to **'GP15SET'**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7bd3a5/3

And I guess thet same expectation you have for `'VASO VETRO 1000'` vs `' VASO VETRO 1000'`

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in your insert

in some row you have

```
  'VASO VETRO 1000',
```

in other you have

```
   ' VASO VETRO 1000',
```

you have an extra space in the start of the field then your where can't work ...

Comment: If the answers are useful you can rate them

Answer (score 0):

change your query to this

```
SELECT SUM(numconffattmiele) 
FROM dettconffattmiele 
WHERE TRIM(codconffattmiele) = 'GP15SET' 
 AND  TRIM(boxfattmiele) = 'VASO VETRO 1000';
```

the issue is you have some additional white spaces in your fields and its not matching correctly

[FIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0a0db/1)

it looks like you are putting a space in your string... aka.

```
value=' $cod16conffattmiele'
-------^-------------------- extra space there
```

you need to remove that space `value='$cod16conffattmiele'`

Comment: the error come from form : value=' $cod16conffattmiele'

Comment: @user2024752 sure thing! glad i could help. a few things to note. TRIM() is just a basic trim function that is in all other programming languages. it pulls out any additional whitespace. your tables values have an additional space in them, so its not matching on an exact comparison unless you "trim" out the extra whitespace. another thing `value=' $cod16conffattmiele'` remove the white space in there to be this `value='$cod16conffattmiele'`. final thing. if you could mark this answer as accepted since its fixes your problem I'd greatly appreciate it!